# TDS shows error 500 when syncing with Sitecore - how to fix?

Tags: tds

I've deployed a local instance of our Sitecore project and I'm trying to get TDS to work. The tests page shows all green:

[image]

However when attempting to click on *Sync with Sitecore* I receive a 500 error:

[image]

And the TDS log shows the following:

```
Exception ProtocolException:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.Version()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CheckClientVersion(TdsServiceSoapClient client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean retry)


Inner Exception Details:
Exception The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (WebException):
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
Exception An error occured getting the TDS service version. Please review the Sitecore logs and/or windows events on the server to determine the problem. (ApplicationException):
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(String sitecoreWebUrl, String sitecoreAccessGuid, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode syncRoot, Boolean sycnChildren)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreProjectPackage.ShowSitecoreSyncWindow(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode selectedItem, Boolean syncChildren)
Exception ProtocolException:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.Version()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CheckClientVersion(TdsServiceSoapClient client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean retry)


Inner Exception Details:
Exception The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (WebException):
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
Exception An error occured getting the TDS service version. Please review the Sitecore logs and/or windows events on the server to determine the problem. (ApplicationException):
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(String sitecoreWebUrl, String sitecoreAccessGuid, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode syncRoot, Boolean sycnChildren)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreProjectPackage.ShowSitecoreSyncWindow(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode selectedItem, Boolean syncChildren)
```

The Sitecore log doesn't show any relevant errors. I am also able to access the */_DEV/TdsService.asmx* page without an error. What could I do to fix the TDS connection?

Comment: Maybe a connection is not possible. Try adding your local test domain to your hosts file.

Comment: Already done. The Sitecore instance itself is accessible from the browser through the local test domain.

Comment: Usually caused by bad URL within TDS settings and/or bad physical path to sitecore instance.

Comment: hit this issue myself - i deleted the _Dev folder in my www root and re-installed the tds service

Comment: in my case it was using the **http** in sitecore url. changing to the **https** fixed to issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as luck might have it, fiddling around with the Sitecore Web Url mysteriously fixed the error. I'm not sure what caused it, possibly a badly cached URL within TDS.

Answer (score 2):

we too had faced this earlier and from what I remember, TDS sync will break if the Sitecore instance for any reason could not be accessed in a browser.
During the time you received the error, if you had tried browsing your local sitecore instance it too would have thrown error. Once the Sitecore instance is up and running, the TDS sync should also work.